Issue with adding custom content to email via Elementor Pro Forms
I'm encountering a challenge with Elementor Pro forms. I need to append a simple line of text ("Additional Text") to the end of emails triggered by form submissions. However, the twist is that I also need to process some data with PHP and include this processed information in the email, so I need it in function.php. Unfortunately, my current setup isn't working as expected, and the additional content doesn't appear in the emails.
I'm seeking a code example or guidance on effective processing and including PHP data in the form submission email. I would greatly appreciate your input and assistance if anyone has tackled a similar issue or has insights on why my additional text might not be appended to the email content.
Here’s what I’ve been trying:
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function($record, $handler) {
    if (!($record instanceof \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Form_Record) || !($handler instanceof \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Ajax_Handler)) {
        return;
    }

    $custom_text = "Additional Text";

    add_filter('elementor_pro/forms/content', function($email_content) use ($custom_text) {
        return $email_content . '<br>' . $custom_text;
    });
}, 10, 2);


I'm not familiar with Elementor's filter hooks in general but according to the documentation looks like you should be using the elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_message hook instead? (Also there's no documentation on that elementor_pro/forms/content hook you're using, are you sure it's a valid one?)

As @cabrerahector suggested on his comment, elementor_pro/forms/content  is not documented on elementor's knowledgebase, so you should use elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_message instead. Also, I'd suggest to replace the elementor_pro/forms/new_record hook with elementor_pro/forms/process, which fires after the forms fields have been validated and processed. The following code should work:
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/process', function($record, $handler) {

    $custom_text = "Additional Text";

    add_filter('elementor_pro/forms/wp_mail_message', function($email_content) use ($custom_text) {
        return $email_content . '<br>' . $custom_text;
    });
}, 10, 2);

